# How to update multiple rows in zend with different values and wheres in one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework

How can I change this raw query to the Zend based one:

```
UPDATE my_table SET publish = 1, cat_id = 1 WHERE article_id = 6
UPDATE my_table SET publish = 1, cat_id = 4 WHERE article_id = 16
UPDATE my_table SET publish = 1, cat_id = 6 WHERE article_id = 35
UPDATE my_table SET publish = 1, cat_id = 8 WHERE article_id = 14
```

I tried this but didn't work:

```
$cat_ids = array(1,4,6,8);
$article_ids = array(6,16,35,14);
$table->update(array('publish' => 1, 'cat_id = ?' => $cat_ids), array('article_id = ?' => $article_ids));
```

Comment: Have a look at [this SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038838/is-it-possible-to-update-multiple-rows-at-the-time-using-zend-db-table).  Because each of your updates are using different logic, I don't think you can combine them.  If the sets were the same but with different where conditions, then it might be possible.

Comment: You mean I should put it in a loop and update 4 times? Or is it possible to create an string which contains the conditions needed and update once?

Comment: What I'm saying is that I think you need 4 separate update statements in MySQL for this.  You _could_ use a single statement with a `CASE` expression, but I don't think that is what your Zend syntax is trying to do.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen could you give me an example with that CASE? But I think it's possible to concatenate columns, values in a loop but I don't know how in ZEND!

Comment: I can give you a single raw MySQL query, but you might have to run it as is in your PHP code.